# Displaying a view controller causes a problem later

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm developing an app that uses Dropbox with SwiftyDropbox.  I'm also trying to use a model controller based on this post...
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-right-way-to-share-state-between-swift-view-controllers--cms-28474

So, before introducing the screen, everything worked fine except that it displayed a black screen until the file download completed.  So I introduced another screen to display until the download completed.  When I introduced that screen, the sequence of events changed, and now the app doesn't work.

Here's my console log without the "wait" screen (with comments identified by "***")

```
AppDelegate: about to check for authorized client

*** Black screen appears at this point

AppDelegate: We have an authorized client.  Now let's see if we can get the file attributes
AppDelegate.checkForDropboxAccess: File serverModified: 2019-01-22 19:34:04 +0000
AppDelegate:downloadNvelopes()
<NSProgress: 0x280bd0320> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 283 of 283  
AppDelegate.downloadNvelopes: we got a response


*** Modelcontroller sets up the data for NvelopesViewController

ModelController.init() start
ModelController.init() finish

*** Everything is set up, and NvelopesViewController works perfectly

NvelopesViewController.viewDidLoad
```

Here's my console log when I add in the "wait" screen (with comments identified by "***")

```
NvelopesWaitViewController.viewDidLoad
*** The wait screen is loaded

AppDelegate: about to check for authorized client
AppDelegate: We have an authorized client.  Now let's see if we can get the file attributes
AppDelegate.checkForDropboxAccess: File serverModified: 2019-01-22 19:34:04 +0000
AppDelegate:downloadNvelopes()
<NSProgress: 0x280e94640> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 283 of 283  
AppDelegate.downloadNvelopes: we got a response
NvelopesViewController.viewDidLoad

NvelopesViewController.viewDidLoad: nada
*** the if let failed

ModelController.init() start
ModelController.init() finish
*** the ModelController is too late!
```

Here's my code in the AppDelegate where I display the wait screen:

```
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        self.window?.rootViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbNvelopesWait") as UIViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

and here's my code where I display the "regular" screen:

```
                self.window?.rootViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbNvelopes") as UIViewController
                if let nvelopesViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as? NvelopesViewController {
                    nvelopesViewController.modelController = ModelController()
                }

                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Notice, I'm instantiating the model controller in nvelopesViewController.  That triggers the code in modelcontroller.  But when I introduce the "wait" screen, that code does not finish in time before the regular view controller is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a resolution.  I used a second variable for Window, and that resolved it.  Here's the code before (which failed)...

```
    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        self.window?.rootViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbNvelopesWait") as UIViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

.
.
.

                self.window?.rootViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbNvelopes") as UIViewController
                if let nvelopesViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as? NvelopesViewController {
                    nvelopesViewController.modelController = ModelController()
                }

                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

and here's the code after, which did work:

```
    var window: UIWindow?
    var window1: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        self.window1 = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        self.window1?.rootViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbNvelopesWait") as UIViewController
        self.window1?.makeKeyAndVisible()
.
.
.
                self.window?.rootViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbNvelopes") as UIViewController
                if let nvelopesViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as? NvelopesViewController {
                    nvelopesViewController.modelController = ModelController()
                }

                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Can someone please explain what is happening here, why using a separate variable for Window corrected the problem?

Thanks!